# Webpack dynamic import not working properly with React nested route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

I am using **Webpack 3.8.1** and **React 16.6.3**, I am using `React.Lazy` to lazy load a component which is nested in a route like `/vehicles/:vehicleId`. In this case, when I am trying to load the component, it sends the HTTP request to 
`/vehicle/static/js/1.7ed7c333.chunk.js` instead of `/static/js/1.7ed7c333.chunk.js` thus making an ERR_ABORTED 404 request.

Request for any clue to solve the problem is appreciated.

*On debugging:* I found that if I change the route to `/vehicles/` the lazy loads works fine, but I can't change my route endpoint due to the requirement.

In `package.json` I have `"homepage": "./"` because I need to serve the page from a custom path, not root.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: lazy(() =>
  import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ "./:file_path")
);